# How to send boolean from main activity to base adapter

Tags: java, android, crash

This is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference ();
    private JazzyListView listView;
    int check=0;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<String> ListString = new ArrayList<String> ();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main22);
        final PullToRefreshView pullToRefreshView=(PullToRefreshView) findViewById (R.id.pull);
        pullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener (new PullToRefreshView.OnRefreshListener () {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                ListString.clear ();
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child ("User");
                            for(DataSnapshot s: snapshot.getChildren ())
                            {
                                if(s.getValue ().toString ().isEmpty ())
                                    Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                                else
                                    ListString.add(s.getKey ().toString ());
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                            pullToRefreshView.setRefreshing (false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        Connectivity connectivity = new Connectivity (MainActivity.this);
        if(connectivity.isConnected ()){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
            progressDialog.setMessage ("Loading");
            progressDialog.setTitle ("Retrieving Data");
            progressDialog.show ();
            ListString.add ("Adding");
            adapter = new MyAdapter (MainActivity.this, ListString);
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener () {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    check++;
                    if(check<=1) {
                        ListString.remove ("Adding");
                        DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child ("User");
                        for(DataSnapshot s: snapshot.getChildren ())
                        {
                            if(s.getValue ().toString ().isEmpty ())
                                Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                            else
                                ListString.add(s.getKey ().toString ());
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss ();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                    }else{

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
            });
        }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("No Network")
                        .setMessage ("No Network Available").setPositiveButton ("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss ();
                    }
                }) ;
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create ();
                alertDialog.show ();
        }

        listView = (JazzyListView) findViewById (R.id.listview);
        listView.setTransitionEffect (new FadeEffect ());
        listView.setAdapter (adapter);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, int i, long l) {
                final String itemname = adapterView.getItemAtPosition (i).toString ();
                try{
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Present?")
                            .setMessage ("Present or Absent:").setPositiveButton ("Present", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            try{
                                //view.setBackgroundColor (getColor (android.R.color.holo_green_light));
                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
                                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
                                DatabaseReference user = databaseReference.child ("Attendence");
                                DatabaseReference date = user.child (simpleDateFormat.format (calendar.getTime ()));
                                DatabaseReference name = date.child (itemname);
                                name.setValue ("Present");
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                            }
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton ("Absent", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
                            DatabaseReference user = databaseReference.child ("Attendence");
                            DatabaseReference date = user.child (simpleDateFormat.format (calendar.getTime ()));
                            DatabaseReference name = date.child (itemname);
                            name.setValue ("Absent");
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create ();
                    alertDialog.show ();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is my MyAdapter.java file:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List thisList;
    Context thiscontext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyAdapter(Context context,List list) {
        thiscontext = context;
        thisList = list;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  thisList.size ();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return thisList.get (i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list_main, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.textView);
        String upper = thisList.get (i).toString ().substring (0,1).toUpperCase () + thisList.get (i).toString ().substring (1);
        TextView boxText = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.boxText);
        TextView boxView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.boxView);
        String first = thisList.get (i).toString ().toUpperCase ().substring (0,1);
        textView.setText (upper);
        boxText.setText (first);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I would like to do that when ever the user click the list item, the list should send the present to boxView TextView in MyAdapter.java class through MainActivity.java and then boxView should set the present or absent in each item of the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you start with creating a new boolean variable in your MyAdapter class. Then, you create new method setPresent() for example and use it to set the boolean value you need.

Your code changed:

In the activity

```
builder.setTitle("Present?")
                            .setMessage ("Present or Absent:").setPositiveButton ("Present", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            try{
                                //view.setBackgroundColor (getColor (android.R.color.holo_green_light));
                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
                                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
                                DatabaseReference user = databaseReference.child ("Attendence");
                                DatabaseReference date = user.child (simpleDateFormat.format (calendar.getTime ()));
                                DatabaseReference name = date.child (itemname);
                                name.setValue ("Present");
                                adapterView.updateView(true, i); // to get the present value form your alert;

                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                            }
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton ("Absent", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
                            DatabaseReference user = databaseReference.child ("Attendence");
                            DatabaseReference date = user.child (simpleDateFormat.format (calendar.getTime ()));
                            DatabaseReference name = date.child (itemname);
                            name.setValue ("Absent");
                            adapterView.updateView(false, i); // to get the absent value form your alert;

                        }
                    });
```

In your adapter;

```
 public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        List thisList;
        Context thiscontext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        public MyAdapter(Context context,List list) {
            thiscontext = context;
            thisList = list;
            inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return  thisList.size ();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return thisList.get (i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }
        // new method

        private void updateView(Boolean value, int index){
        View v = thisList.getChildAt(index - 
        thisList.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        if(v == null)
        return;

        TextView boxView = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.boxView);
        if (value && value != null) {
        boxView.setText("Present");
        } else if (!value && value !=null) {
        boxView.setText("Absent");
        }
```

}

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list_main, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.textView);
            String upper = thisList.get (i).toString ().substring (0,1).toUpperCase () + thisList.get (i).toString ().substring (1);
            TextView boxText = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.boxText);
            TextView boxView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.boxView);
            String first = thisList.get (i).toString ().toUpperCase ().substring (0,1);
            textView.setText (upper);
            boxText.setText (first);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

After setting the value you should notify the adapter there was a change in the row. That's it ! You passed the boolean value.

Comment: Sorry but this doesnt worked. What I want is that when on listview item user clicked then a dialog box appers and at dialog box user selects true or false and the I would like to sent that true and false to listview adapter to display it. To display this text we have boxView textview in MyAdapter

Comment: Yeah, man , I get it i'll add the finished complete  code to my answer now, if you cannot adapt mine right away

Comment: Well, I think it's what you wanted as I get it. Let me know it you need smth else

Comment: It is working but it is updating all the boxView items as present or absent same

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer which I got through thinking, which actually worked for me:

Rather than using boolean I used HashMap function and stored different values for different item positions:

```
map.put (String.valueOf (postion), "1");
```

where postion is the position of the item in Integers.

```
map.put (String.valueOf (postion), "0");
```

and then I created the function setMap in MyAdapter.java which sets the hashMap value of MyAdapter.java

```
public void setPresent(Map map1){
    map = map1;
    Log.e ("Inner Length", String.valueOf (map.toString ()));
}
```

and accessing the values of different positions let me to do what i want.